# scala.js add dom library does not work

Tags: sbt, scala.js

I am following scala.js tutorial here: http://www.scala-js.org/doc/tutorial.html. I added `libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules.scalajs" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "0.6"` to build.sbt and called reload from sbt, but it failed:

> C:\work\projects\scalajstest\project\build.sbt:3: error: value %%% is not a member of String
>   libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules.scalajs" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "0.6
>   "
>                                                           ^
>   [error] Type error in expression
>   Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?

How to solve this issue? I tried to google something with no success. I am using SBT version 0.13.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should go in `scalajstest/build.sbt`, not in `project/build.sbt`. Remember that all paths in the tutorial are relative to your project's base directory, which is `scalajstest`.